# How do quotient group interact with product groups?

Tags: group-theory

So I'm working with $\mathbb{Z}\times C_{4}$ but I'm unclear as to what I get if I quotient by $C_{2}$. Does $\mathbb{Z}\times C_{4}/C_{2}=\mathbb{Z}\times C_{2}$ or am I totally misunderstanding how they work? And what would the morphisms $G/C_{2}\rightarrow G/C_{4}$ be? Wouldn't they just be trivial or the identity as $C_{2}$ is contained in $C_{4}$?

Comment: How do you define $C_4$  or $C_2$?

Comment: The cyclic groups of order 4 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Why would $C_2$ be contained in $C_4$  then?

Comment: As there's a cyclic subgroup of order 2 in $C_{4}$.

Comment: Then it's *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $C_4$, that's all.

Comment: @Bernard, equal is fine here, as $C_2$ is defined only up to isomorphism.  If we were talking about $\mathbb Z/2$ and $\mathbb Z/4$ it would be a different situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K \leq G$ and $L \leq H$ are normal subgroups then $K \times L$ is naturally a normal subgroup of $G \times H$ and there is an isomorphism
$$(G \times H)/(K \times L) \simeq (G/K) \times (H/L).$$
In your case you are quotienting $\mathbb Z \times C_4$ by $1 \times C_2$ and you get $(\mathbb Z/1) \times (C_4/C_2) \simeq \mathbb Z \times C_2$.

Comment: And what about the morphisms $G/C_{2}\rightarrow G/C_{4}$ then?

Comment: If you mod out $C_4$ then you're eliminating an entire factor, so $G/C_4 \simeq \mathbb Z$ and the morphism $G/C_2 \to G/C_4 \simeq \mathbb Z$ is just projection to the $\mathbb Z$ factor.

Comment: So just for example $(a,b)\mapsto a$?

Comment: Yes.  That's the map I'm talking about.

Comment: But then what would the corresponding $G$-map $C_{2}\rightarrow C_{4}$ be?

Comment: What do you mean the "corresponding" map?

Comment: Would there not then be a $G$-map $C_{2}\rightarrow C_{4}$?